# Liferay set session and read it on specific pages

Tags: java, forms, session, liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to set session that can be manipulated across pages, i was able to set the session using this code

```
HttpSession session1 = request.getSession(false);
String foo = (String) session1.getAttribute("password");
session1.setAttribute("password","authenticated");
out.println(foo);
```

This code is written in Custom JSP hook (**Journal_content/view.jsp**)

I also checked if the session is saved on the browser and it's there. When i go from one page to another, i can't read the session so it's re asking me to put the password code.

Can anyone tell me how to make this in Liferay?.

Comment: where have you written this code?

Comment: @PrakashK I edited the post, and included what type am i using and where excatly.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `PortletSession` instead of `HttpSession` like this:

```
PortletSession portletSession = renderRequest.getPortletSession();
portletSession.setAttribute("password", "authenticated", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

... and for fetching the attribute:

```
String pwd = (String) portletSession.getAttribute("password", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

Since liferay's OOTB portlets define `<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>` in their `liferay-portlet.xml`, the above code shares the `session` with the whole portal.

A small note from the `liferay-portlet.xml` DTD regarding using `<private-session-attributes>`:

> Set the `private-session-attributes` value to true if the portlet does not share session attributes with the portal. The default value is true. The property `session.shared.attributes` in portal.properties specifies which session attributes are shared even when the private-session-attributes value is true.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted my answer [here](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/27833542) to share object from Hooks to Portlet.

If you want to share Objects between portlets then you have to set false in liferay-portlet.xml file of originating portlet.